# How to get hello world to change colors on every click?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to complete a project and I feel as if I am just right there. Any advice would help greatly. The goal is to get *hello world* to change to one of the six colors on a click and have the color change on each click.

```
Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (ch) {
            case 0:
                t.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                break;
            case 1:
                t.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                break;
            case 2:
                t.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                break;
            case 3:
                t.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                break;
            case 4:
                t.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
                break;
            case 5:
                t.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `ch` as `int` type and initialize with 0.

Add `ch=(ch+1)%5;` in `onClick`.